# OPENJSON Insert Select by Row

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, json

I have some JSON which I can successfully insert into a table, but there are some values I need to perform addtional queries on per 'row' of json. I cannot seem to perform the select within the 'With' of OPENJSON like so:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (Json1, Json2, Json3, Json4, Test1)

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH(
Json1 NVARCHAR(10), '$.Json1',
Json2 NVARCHAR(10), '$.Json2',
Json3 NVARCHAR(10), '$.Json3',
Json4 NVARCHAR(10), '$.Json4',
SELECT Value1 from AnotherTable where AnotherTable.Value = '$.Json4')
```

`Value1` should go into `Test1` on my `Test` table, which should be dynamic for each 'row' in the json.

Anyone know the correct syntax to do this, if even possible?

Comment: Please add sample JSON and desired output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Json NVARCHAR(4000);

DECLARE @AnotherTable TABLE
(
    [Value] NVARCHAR(10),
    Value1 NVARCHAR(10)
);

SET @Json
    = N'{
         "Test":[
                   { "Json1":"a","Json2":"b","Json3":"c","Json4":"d" },
                   { "Json1":"e","Json2":"f","Json3":"g","Json4":"h" }
                ]
        }';

INSERT INTO @AnotherTable
(
    [Value],
    Value1
)
VALUES
('d', 'dd'),
('h', 'hh');

/* INSERT INTO TEST (Json1, Json2, Json3, Json4, Test1) */
SELECT OJ.Json1,
       OJ.Json2,
       OJ.Json3,
       OJ.Json4,
       A.Value1 AS Test1
FROM @AnotherTable AS A
    INNER JOIN
    OPENJSON(@Json, '$.Test')
    WITH
    (
        Json1 NVARCHAR(10) '$.Json1',
        Json2 NVARCHAR(10) '$.Json2',
        Json3 NVARCHAR(10) '$.Json3',
        Json4 NVARCHAR(10) '$.Json4'
    ) AS OJ
        ON OJ.Json4 = A.[Value];
```

Results:-

| Json1 | Json2 | Json3 | Json4 | Test1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | dd |
| e | f | g | h | hh |